# A games/matches schedule

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

Suppose I have 8 teams $A_1,\ldots, A_8$, competing in different 8 games $X_1,\ldots, X_8$. For example $X_1 = soccer, X_2 = basket ball, \ldots,$
. In the morning there are 4 games $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ take place, with 16 matches. In the afternoon there are another 4 games $X_5,X_6,X_7,X_8$ take place with 16 matches again. Can I schedule (I can freely choose any game) such that:

a) Every team participate in 4 different games in the morning and 4 different games in the afternoon.

b) Every team has a change to meet with another 7 teams?

c) Each games need two teams to play in one match?

Comment: In this scenario $8$ teams play $8$ matches each. If they each play against every other team they will have to play one team twice. Is that OK? If not, you need to change your requirements. Maybe each team plays only seven matches, with one bye time.

Comment: See http://tournamentscheduler.net/ , which I found as the first entry on the Related list of questions on this site.

Comment: That is okay, how can I schedule?

Comment: The pointis I need 8 different games, means 8 different sports for example.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. Different sports and different teams? Please edit the question to write out a complete list of the games to be played (not how they are scheduled) if there were $4$ teams, A, B, C and D. So start with A plays B. What sport?  There should be just $6$ games if each team plays every other team once. Would that mean $4$ sports?  I'm also confused about the difference between games and matches. Name everything. Do this in the question, not by continuing the discussion in comments.

Comment: Hi just edited that, I am so sorry for causing confusion!

Comment: I'm still confused. Must the morning sports for each team be different from the afternoon sports, so each team plays all $8$ sports? Please edit the question to include a _complete schedule_ for a smaller tournament. For each match list the teams and the sport.That's the only way I can do any more thinking about your problem. Use "sports" and"matches". The word "games" is part of the confusion. (By the way, I suspect the answer is that there's no such schedule.)